# How to count rows in a while loop using pdo fetch

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, counter

I was using mysqli_fetch_array and the counting was right until I changed to fetch(), which now only returns the total number of rows instead of returning each number for each row.

So for row one, I want to echo "1", and so on.

**NEW NOTE** :Everything else inside the while statement is returning correct values, except the counter which returns the total number of rows whereas I want a row number in the order that it was selected from the sql statement.

**As requested. This is my connection.**

I don't know if i'm suppose to be checking " $e->getMessage();" on every query since I'm using this connection for all my queries.

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db;charset=utf8', 'usr', 'pwd',
                    array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
                          PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
                  );
} catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**This worked**

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM music');

$count = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $count++; 
    echo $count;
}
```

**The new doesn't work.**

```
$query = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM music');

$count = 0;
while($row = $query->fetch()){
    $count++; 
    echo $count;
}
```

Comment: are you still using mysqli or now PDO?

Comment: @iswinky, Yes i'm using pdo

Comment: have you looked into this: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php ??

Comment: PDOStatement::rowCount — Returns the number of rows affected by the last SQL statement

Comment: PDO have a little different behavior. This is a replacement for your mysqli (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199122/how-to-count-rows-in-a-while-loop-using-pdo-fetch/25367887#25367887).

Answer (score 2):

Works fine, use a try catch do see if your PDO connection is working.

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'root', 'root',
                       array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
}  catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM music';
$sth = $dbh->query($sql);

$count = 0;
while($row = $sth->fetch()){
    $count++; 
    echo $count;
}
```

I've just tested this and it works fine. Either your PDO connection is incorrect or your query returns no results. I suggest you `var_dump($dbh)` and see if it returns a PDO object or check that your query is correct. Is your table called `music`? It is case sensitive.

You also need to change your connection form mysqli to PDO

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
```

to

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'user', 'password');
```

You can also throw PDO exceptions to see if any are occuring:
`PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`

Comment: Can u please explain what's making what i've done not to work and why this will work?

Comment: You haven't called `execute()` on the the $query object

Comment: Why are you using prepare, this statement doesn't have to be prepared? I'm not using any external values in my question

Comment: My bad. Your code looks correct, have you checked your PDO object?

Comment: Try using a try catch block and change your mysqli connection to PDO if you haven't already

Comment: ohhhh yes that is in my connection, should i add it in there? Because the structure of your code makes it impossible to use this connection as a template for other queries. Ill edit the code and show you how im checking the object.

Comment: Yeah this is just an example. You can decalre your PDO connection outside the try catch block, this was just to check for errors though. You can also use a singleton pattern (more advanced)

Comment: Yeah you don't need to wrap the entire thing in a try catch, just the connection itself. So you could store this connection in a different file, include that file then access the $dbh variable to run queries

Comment: @user3109875 are you still having issues? This should work, unless your PDO object isn't instantiated correctly

Comment: -1 It's a copy of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199122/how-to-count-rows-in-a-while-loop-using-pdo-fetch/25367887#25367887

Comment: @pc-shooter the answer you linked to is _newer_ than this answer

Comment: @pc-shooter yeah...pretty sure wrote this like two weeks ago haha

Comment: @iswinky OOps sorry for that! If you edit your answer, I' rollback my downvote

Answer (score 0):

$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/pdo-select-query-fetch

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
if ($pdo){  
    $query=$pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM music");
    if($query->execute()){
        $count = $query->fetch()[0];//or fetch()['cnt'] 
        echo $count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PDO have a little different behavior. This is a replacement for your mysqli.

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'user', 'password',array(
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        // optional
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND    => 'SET NAMES utf8',
    ));

    $count = 0;
    foreach ($dbh->query("SELECT * FROM `music`") as $row) {
        $count++; 
        echo $count;
    }
}  catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    exit();
}
```

I hope that helped.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `PDO::FETCH_NUM` to get the row count directly :-

```
$countquery = $dbh->query('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM music');
$rowCount = 0;
$rowCount = $countquery ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
echo $rowCount;
//And then do another query for the real data if need be
```

***** This makes use of a query to get the row count, and saves you the time taken by the while loop.

Comment: ...and instead sends out same query to server twice, effectively doubling servers work load. I wouldn't prefer this way unless I know for certain that the data I'm querying is very small and creating the result set will be trivial for server.

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu `SELECT COUNT(1) ...` is a very light query, it is usually the recomended option in mysql of getting the size of the result set before doing a heavier query, especially when using innodb. Besides, iterating over all rows scales (very) badly as the number of rows increases.